# How can I fix this? “XRAY: transport/internet/websocket: failed to serve http for WebSocket > accept tcp [::]:8443: use of closed network connection.”

Tags: networking, vpn, tcp, tls, websocket

Recently I bought a Germany based VPS server to create my own VPN using v2ray because I live in Iran and the internet is heavily censored here.

I connected my domain to CloudFlare CDN to avoid my actual server IP from getting leaked and I have SSL activated on my domain. I created a VPN config using vless on port 443 and websocket as transmission because I’m using a CDN and using my domain as SNI while having TLS activated.

This config works just fine but when I try to create any other config using the vmess or vless on any other https port I get this error:

> WARNING - XRAY: transport/internet/websocket: failed to serve http for WebSocket > accept tcp [::]:8443: use of closed network connection.

And when I try to connect to the config it gives me a TLS handshake error/timeout. I’ve checked the ports and they are not blocked but I have no idea how to solve this issue.

As i said above I’ve tried checking if any of the ports are blocked but from what i know they weren’t, and i’ve tried to set the TLS version of my CloudFlare to 1.2/1.3 and the same in my config as well and that didn’t help.